# What happened to QTikZ for Windows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors, ktikz

QTikZ is a fabulous little editor that allows you to enter TikZ code and see a real-time preview of your figure. It was available for download for MS Windows at

[`http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/`](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/)

but that website now appears to be down. Does anybody know (a) what has become of the QTikZ project, and (b) whether there is an alternative place to obtain a copy of QTikZ for Windows?

Comment: You can check also [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/), another live code tikz editor.

Comment: @Kpym Unfortunately, TikzEdt is no more maintained as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The source code lives on http://github.com/fhackenberger/ktikz (last update in September 2015), and an archived copy of the website from September 2015 can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20150921123912/http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/

Comment: Its still live at https://github.com/fhackenberger/ktikz
Just for some reason the website is no longer being updated