# Qtikz, and packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, ktikz

How can i use packages in Qtikz ? 

I want to use for example circuitikz package in Qtikz. How can I load this package to Qtikz ?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Why did you put the `ktikz` tag for `Qtikz`? What is the relation between the two?

Comment: I cannot find a tag named as Qtikz so i think they are similar programs thats why i put it there.

Comment: Okay. The reason there's no Qtikz tag is because not many people know it. What is Qtikz?

Comment: It is a kind of application to create tikz figures.

Comment: In this case, it seems to me that your question is to be asked in support of this application.

Comment: Exactly, but there is no handbook manual about this application. That's why i asked this question.

Comment: Where do we find this application?

Comment: @AndréC They are the same program see links in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288617

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Github page for KtikZ](https://github.com/fhackenberger/ktikz/) contains a document [index.html](https://github.com/fhackenberger/ktikz/blob/master/doc/index.html) (see also the [rendered version](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fhackenberger/ktikz/blob/master/doc/index.html)) with the title *The QtikZ Handbook*, so it seems that this is the QtikZ documentation. From there (section 3, emphasis mine):

> ### Templates
>
> QtikZ features a template mechanism. A template file is a skeleton
> LaTeX file in which **all necessary packages and definitions are loaded**
> and in which the style (fonts, ...) is determined. A template file
> does (usually) not contain any real contents, instead it contains a
> “replacement string” (which is <> by default) which is replaced by the
> TikZ code in the editor when the preview is generated.
>
> When the preview is generated, QtikZ internally replaces the
> “replacement string” in the template file by the TikZ code in the
> editor and compiles the resulting LaTeX file. The resulting PDF file
> is then displayed in the Preview panel. If any errors occur during
> compilation (both errors in the TikZ code and in the template file),
> they are displayed in the Messages panel.
>
> The user can **create template files and specify the full path in the
> Template text field**. If the Template text field is empty while
> generating the preview, an internal template file is used, so the user
> is not forced to create a template file.
>
> For example, a template file named `ktikz_template.pgs` could contain
> the following:
>
> Example 3.2. An example template file
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{mathptmx}
> \usepackage{tikz}
> \usepackage{color}
> \DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsb}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
> \SetSymbolFont{symbolsb}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
> \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbolsb}
> \usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
> \PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
> \PreviewEnvironment[]{pgfpicture}
> \begin{document}
> <>
> \end{document}
> ```

So in the template you can add other packages. The manual also has a screenshot that shows the location of the text field where you can put the path to the template, although the screenshot is for KtikZ, so that is a bit confusing.